# How to find change points in a graph on matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, statistics, time-series

I have a graph like this
[image: Graph1]

I need to find points at which sudden changes happening for the DPC Time Curve. We can observe that at time 20 and around 70 increase is happening. How to do this in Matlab. Is there any method or predefined functions available to find this change points?
Also how to represent the change point on the graph?

Comment: Do you have access to the time series?  If so, you could use the built in function, diff, which will return a vector of differences between successive points.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data for `DPC Time Curve` starts with zero and calling it as `dpc_time` for the sake of understanding the code, think this might work for you -

```
t1 = find(dpc_time~=0)
t2 = diff(t1)==1
t3 = strfind(num2str([0 t2'],'%1d'),'01') %%//'
changing_pts = t1(t3)
```

Comment: Which package has the `find` function?

Comment: @Max We are talking MATLAB here and the function is documented [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got confused - thought this was related to R.